# Build Visual Studio project on TeamCity server installed on Ubuntu

Tags: c, visual-studio, ubuntu, mono, teamcity

I'm setting up a TeamCity server on Linux for building C projects, created in Visual Studio. When I make a new project on the TeamCity server with the C-code and run it, I get the error:

> Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration.
>   Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration
>   requirements.

I installed MONO on the Linux server, but still getting the error. Is there some configuration I need to do or should I add a build agent? I know such projects need a Windows Framework, but I thought the MONO should solve that.

Answer (score 4):

In order to build Visual Studio project you will need Windows agent (with VS installed). You can attach up to 3 agents to your TC server for free. 
Find instructions [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents).

---

You cannot build Visual Studio project on Linux - in the build you will get prerequisite that the VS is installed on the agent (you can see it in requirements tab I guess).

Installing Mono wont help (this is .Net runtime, not C compiler).

---

If you want to build Linux version of your application from the same sources you will need dedicated project (makefile/cmake) that will handle Linux based build.